# Can Windows 7 be installed on Mac OS X Extended filesystem?

Tags: windows-7, macos, filesystems, truecrypt, vmware-fusion

I want to create a VM that is encrypted using TrueCrypt. To do this I create a TrueCrypt volume. I noticed the options are FAT32 or Mac OSX extended. Since I'm planning on installing Windows 7 with VMware Fusion, which should I choose?
[image: TrueCrypt Volume Creation Wizard]
I've done it using FAT before and Windows seems to be able to install, though I can't have files larger than 4GB and I found some problems changing the disk size through Fusion.

Is it that the TrueCrypt volume may be one file system but VMware adds another layer of abstraction so it's irrelevant? Actually since the .vmwarevm file is much larger than 4GB this could really screw things up. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using a physical hard disk or a VHD for the windows guest install?

Comment: Where exactly are you selecting FAT32? Best provide a screenshot. I don’t remember anything like that in Fusion.

Comment: Windows 7 can't be installed to FAT32, so it's not an option anyways.

Comment: @DanielB oops I meant when I used TrueCrypt to build a partition it only gave the options of FAT32 and Mac OSX extended

Comment: And how exactly does TrueCrypt relate to Fusion? I still don’t get it, sorry. While you’re at it, you could include all the details of your nifty plan in the original question. (:

Comment: @DanielB ok fixed question

Answer (score 4):

No, Windows 7 can't read HFS+ (Mac OS Extended), so it can't boot from it.

NTFS volumes can co-exist on a GPT drive alongside HFS+ partitions, it's just that OS X's Disk Utility doesn't know how to create them.

If you want to use OS X's built-in Disk Utility to repartition your drive and/or resize partitions before installing Windows 7, then have it make a partition of type "Free Space".

Then, start the Windows 7 install process and when it asks you where you want to install Windows, select that free space and have the Windows 7 installer format it as an NTFS volume.

Comment: It is worth mentioning (although not of interest to the OP), that exFAT is a filesystem different from FAT. It can be read and written by both OS X and Windows, but unlinke FAT can also contain large files. I am, however, not sure whether it's possible to boot from it.

Answer (score 0):

You’re confusing a few things. First, the „File“ `VM-Name.vmwarevm` is actually a folder. It contains all the regular files. Next, although your concern would still be valid for the virtual disk file, VMware can already work around that and offers an option to split virtual disks into chunks of 2 GiB. So there wouldn’t be any problem on FAT32.

Since only Fusion itself (not the guest system!) would access the encrypted disk, you can safely choose HFS+. So it is sort-of irrelevant, yes.

But why not simply use [Fusion’s encryption capability](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005714)? It probably offers vastly superior performance and fewer problems.